# How do i prevent users from uploading nsfw content to imgur API

Tags: image, computer-vision, imgur

We are hosting a website and using Imgur API. We don't want people to upload NSFW images. When looking at the documentation I can't seem to find an option to prevent nsfw content from being uploaded. Is there any way? We're using PHP cURL
[PHP cURL]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to automatically scan and filter for nsfw content with the Imgur API alone.

However, you can try using a 3rd party API to detect nsfw content in an image and filter based on the results.

PixLab is an example of an API you could use to accomplish this: https://pixlab.io/cmd?id=nsfw